# Reorder array by given key name

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this:

```
Array
(
    [stripe] => Array
        (
            [title] => Stripe
        )

    [paypal_standard] => Array
        (
            [title] => PayPal Standard
        )
)
```

Given the key 'paypal_standard', how can I reorder the array so that this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [paypal_standard] => Array
        (
            [title] => PayPal Standard
        )
    [stripe] => Array
        (
            [title] => Stripe
        )
)
```

Perhaps I am missing it, but is there a PHP function for doing this?

Edit: I can't sort by alphabetical order.

Comment: if you already know the order you want, i dont see why you have to reorder the array.

Comment: @Dagon - because I can't control the order of the array.

Comment: why does the order **IN** the array matter, you can extract in any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$response = array(
    'stripe' => array('title' => 'Stripe'),
    'paypal_standard' => array('title' => 'Paypal standard'),
);

$paypal = $response['paypal_standard']; // Filter out the value corresponding to paypal_standard

unset($response['paypal_standard']); // Since filtered out, remove paypal_standard key from array

$response = array('paypal_standard' => $paypal) + $response; // Format the array by adding key value pair for paypal_standard in the beginning
```

Output:

```
Array
(
 [paypal_standard] => Array
    (
        [title] => Paypal standard
    )

 [stripe] => Array
    (
        [title] => Stripe
    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to sort alphabetical - I want to reorder the array so that a specific key is first. But that might not necessarily be by alphabetical order.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!